# Prepopulate Task object data to Case

Tags: apex, process-builder

We have task object as Related List in Account . 
Case is also a related list in Account .

Task is created by Telecom Sales REP .
After Task creation is completed , if Case is created, few fields from Task needs to get auto populated in Case.

Is this possible by Process Builder ?
And how to approach this through apex?

Comment: This could be done through Process Builder and Flow as I think you would probably need to call an autolaunched flow from PB to do the cross object update. Does a Case have to get created every time a Task is created? How are the Case and Task related other than being for the same account?

Comment: @DaveHumm- Case will be created manually . Population of XYZ fields from Task to Case  needs to be done automatically upon creation .